# ajax is not sending data to php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Script. I want to send data to php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "type": "POST",
        "sAjaxSource": "abcd.php",
        "data": [
              { game:"Football" },
              { game:"Baseball" }
              ],
        "aoColumns": [
              { mData: 'name' } ,
              { mData: 'count' }
            ]
      });  
  });
</script>
```

abcd.php (Data is not coming to php page):

```
<?php
   $game=$_POST['game'];
  ?>
```

Comment: remove the `[]` around the data object

Comment: tried,still not working.

Comment: What dataTable plugin are you using?

Comment: for one record i removed[] and it worked. now i want to add 2 records, but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the value of the `game:` parameter an array of all the games you want.

```
    "data": { games: ["Football", "Baseball"] },
```

Then in `abcd.php`, you can do:

```
$games = $_POST['games'];
```

This will be an array, and you can loop over it to process all the games that are requested.

Comment: Thanks for solution.